# How to execute an object's procedure inside a table of said object?

Tags: oracle, object, nested, procedure

as the title says I'm trying to test an object's procedure which is inside a table of said object, and I have no idea how to, unlike the function which is a simple select.
Here's my code

The first object

```
create or replace type t_ingresos is object
(anio number(4),
excedentes number(12),
premios_concedidos number(12));
/
```

A type table for that object

```
create type tab_ingresos as table of t_ingresos;
```

Another object, with procedure in question

```
create or replace type t_beneficios is object
(id_socio number(12),
ingresos tab_ingresos,
map member function f_ordenar return number,
member procedure p_calcular_ingresos)
/

create or replace type body t_beneficios is
    map member function f_ordenar return number is
    begin   
        return self.id_socio;
    end;
    member procedure p_calcular_ingresos is
    v_mov_excedente number(3);
    v_mov_premio number(3);
    v_id_cuenta number(8);
    ind number;
    begin   
        select id_tipo into v_mov_e
            from aho_tipo_movimiento
            where nombre_tipo like '%DE%';
        select id_tipo into v_mov_p
            from aho_tipo_movimiento
            where nombre_tipo like '%P%';
        select id_cuenta into v_id_cuenta
            from aho_cuenta_ahorro
            where id_socio = self.id_socio and rownum = 1;
        ind := self.ingresos.first;
        while ind <= self.ingresos.last loop 
            dbms_output.put_line(self.ingresos(ind).excedentes);
            dbms_output.put_line(self.ingresos(ind).premios_concedidos);
            dbms_output.put_line(v_mov_e);
            dbms_output.put_line(v_mov_p);
            dbms_output.put_line(v_id_cuenta);
        end loop;   
    end;
end;
/
```

And the last table, with a nested table

```
create table socios_beneficios of t_beneficios
nested table ingresos store as ingresos_tab
/
```

I have tried a pl/sql since it was a procedure, but I got 'component 'P_CALCULAR_INGRESOS' must be declared'

```
declare
begin
    socios_beneficios.p_calcular_ingresos();
end;
/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `member procedure` looks for some data in external tables so I created some dummy data to be able to test it.

You can test it by retrieving data from your table like `select value(p) from socios_beneficios p` but it is a bad idea. Why? Because your procedure contains errors. And everytime you correct it you have to drop table because you will have problems when recompiling type where dependent object exists.

So create a simple variable and test procedure:

```
declare
  v_beneficios t_beneficios;
begin
  v_beneficios := t_beneficios(1, tab_ingresos(t_ingresos(11, 101, 1001),
                                               t_ingresos(12, 102, 1002)));
  dbms_output.put_line(v_beneficios.f_ordenar);
  v_beneficios.p_calcular_ingresos;
end;
```

This showed me that definitions for `v_mov_e` and `v_mov_p` are missing. And `v_mov_excedente` and `v_mov_premio` are declared but never used. And there is infinite loop because you were not incrementing `ind`. So corrected procedure is:

```
member procedure p_calcular_ingresos is
  v_mov_e number(3);
  v_mov_p number(3);
  v_mov_excedente number(3);  
  v_mov_premio number(3);
  v_id_cuenta number(8);
  ind number;
begin
    select id_tipo into v_mov_e
        from aho_tipo_movimiento
        where nombre_tipo like '%DE%';
    select id_tipo into v_mov_p
        from aho_tipo_movimiento
        where nombre_tipo like '%P%';
    select id_cuenta into v_id_cuenta
        from aho_cuenta_ahorro
        where id_socio = self.id_socio and rownum = 1;
    ind := self.ingresos.first;
    while ind <= self.ingresos.last loop
        dbms_output.put_line(self.ingresos(ind).excedentes);
        dbms_output.put_line(self.ingresos(ind).premios_concedidos);
        dbms_output.put_line(v_mov_e);
        dbms_output.put_line(v_mov_p);
        dbms_output.put_line(v_id_cuenta);
        ind := ind + 1;
    end loop;
end;
```

I don not know what it does, you are probably building something so it is not finished, I guess. But now it compiles, and our simply test case works.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much! And thanks for the corrections as well.